# Docker build arg with git command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run the command

`docker build --build-arg GIT_DESCRIBE=$(git describe) -f production.dockerfile .`

But then docker complains

`"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`

In my dockerfile I have the lines

```
ARG GIT_DESCRIBE=unspecified
ENV GIT_DESCRIBE ${GIT_DESCRIBE}
```

Comment: What is the output of `git describe`?

Comment: The output is a string

Comment: I'm asking because if there's any whitespace in the output from git describe, it could cause the error you get. I know it's a string :)

Comment: Seems to be no whitespace, but there's `.`'s and `-`'s

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on Linux in a bash shell. It works as it should. What is your host OS and what shell/terminal do you use?

Comment: This is the windows terminal, so that's probably the issue then

Comment: Yeah. You can't use `$(git describe)` on Windows. That's a Linux thing.